# Is there a way to send email alert when Omni-channel is set to offline automatically or by user in salesforce?

Tags: trigger, omnichannel

We have a requirement where we have to send email alert to current user when his/her omni-channel is set to offline. I don't see an option to achieve this using Process Builder. But would like to know if it possible using Trigger.

Comment: If you are using Lightning, a Lightning component can detect the logout event: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_console_events_omnichannellogout.htm

Comment: Only if you were to use platform events could you use a trigger. The console supports platform events. I think you'd need to do it based on a combination of `lightning:omniChannelWorkloadChanged` and `lightning:omniChannelStatusChanged`. I wouldn't want to rely on just reading one of those.